# How to send and receive packages from phone to computer

Tags: networking, python, remote, smartphone

I want a way to "control" my PC without any third party program. Let me explain more. Few days ago I found the Wake On LAN feature, I set it up to my PC and I found it very useful and convenient. I want to set up something similar. I want to send packages from my android phone directly to my computer (like the magic packet mentioned earlier) and then the computer to run a certain python script which I will program. Yes I know that I can set up an Apache web page and run scripts from there but I found it very difficult to set it to run scripts plus that I'll have to open the browser, type the URL and then press the button on the web page. On the other hand, with the packages it will be quicker to send it since it will require less clicks and effort (at least if it is similar to the magic packet...)
Note that I don't have a degree or something (in fact I still go to school), I'm just interested in computers.
If that helps, here is my OS
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Comment: I doubt that such a thing exists. Mainly because of the android part. For remotely executing something on a Linux box, secure shell (or `ssh`) is the preferred way to go. If you do it with a website there are possibilities to create quick launch icons for a website on android ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167594/create-a-android-launch-icon-for-website). But also keep security in mind, you do not want anyone to be able to remote control your computer

Answer (score 1):

Wake-on-LAN works bc. there is a small chip in your network card, which is always on and which will turn your PC on when it receives a certan packet.

So there is a signal (the packet), the connection (your network cable) and someone to act on the signal (that chip).

So you do need similar things running on your PC then. There are plenty of solutions, maybe not exactly what you expect though. And all of them are "third party" solutions. It really depends on what you want to do specifically, but the whole notion of "send and receive packages" is a server.

You could run an SSH server on your computer, which is nice for remote access anyway, but that is a command line/text-based approach. So you have to either use an SSH app on your phone and type all the commands, or implement an Android app that sends these commands on button press.

Or, like you mentioned, a web server. But that is only programmed to support the HTTP protocol, so you still need to write a program that would execute your script when the web server receives a request. That's a web application. A nice way to write those is, for example, with python and a web framework (e.g., python and cherrypy, or python + flask + and a web server). You'd also need write the android app.

So, all of those solutions require either a lot of programming, or aren't so user friendly (SSH solution).

The only existing app I know is Pushbullet, which is for viewing your cell phone notifications/messages/etc on your PC, or to share files and links from your phone to your PC.

Note also that your operating system isn't supposed to do random things someone from outside asks it to do, that'd be a huge security risk. If you write an application like the one I talked about above, you also have to consider security: you don't want someone else to start random command on your computer.
(note that SSH contains a lot of security measures and if set-up correctly, is rather safe).

Comment: It seems like a similar queston was asked before: https://askubuntu.com/questions/509048/how-to-activate-script-on-laptop-from-smartphone

Comment: Specifically what I want to do is to make my computer "ready for duty" remotely through my phone. Lets say for example that I am going home and I want to watch some youtube videos on my computer. So, on my way home, I can turn on my computer through WOL and then I want to run a python script on my computer which will open the youtube site. I have programmed some python scripts like that so thats not a problem. What I had in mind was just a program which would listen to a port for certain packages and run scripts when it receives them, but I think I'll go with SSH bc its safer and easier

Comment: Well another problem showed up. I tried with the SSH as you said and it did exactly what I wanted. I also found an app that sends the command which opens the desired site by just pressing a button. BUT, I can't connect outside of my local network. I have done the port forwarding and I have configured the port at sshd_config. Both `sudo service ssh status` and `sudo netstat -peanut` show that the ssh is running at the correct port. I of course did my research and I found that lots of people have the same problem but none of those answers helped me. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Weeell, that's a whole different topic. You need to read up on some networking basics. Basically, you have one private network "inside" your home and one IP address facing outward. The router uses NAT (network address translation) to translate that. Since you configured port forwarding, you probably know. But even then - it depends on your internet connection and provider. Mine assigns an ISP internal IPv6 address to my router, which is then routed through a shared IPv4 Address to the internet. So I can't have services on the internet at all.

Comment: There are also services that offer to give you a tunnel to your home. Basically your computer connects to their server and their server is reachable on the internet. Like ngrok. A VPN service would probably work as well.
Oh, and since you are new here, accept the answer if it answered your question (the check mark).

Comment: So there isn't any solution for SSH to work outside of the local network? If not then the whole idea goes up in smoke :(. Well your answer helped me a lot but I didn't solve my problem 100%. I will leave it unchecked hoping that someone else might have a solution and answer something. If you have any other idea or solution please let me know. Thanks a lot for your help :D

Comment: No SSH can absolutely work outside of the local network. All I'm saying is, that I don't know your set-up and your internet provider. But there are resources for that topic on the net.